# run the python program as service without installing python?

Tags: python, windows, service

I have written a program that can change the system's IP address/password automatically at a specific time. In addition, it has two separate python files.

The first one is a program that runs the main program under the service, retrieves the desired information from the user and stores it in a `.txt' file.

```
# Import/Lib

import os
import sys
import pysc
import time

# Services


if __name__ == '__main__':
    service_name = 'test4'
    script_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__)+"\\"+"Run.exe"

    )
    pysc.create(
        service_name=service_name,
        cmd=[sys.executable, script_path]

    )
    print("CreateService SUCCESS")
    pysc.start(service_name)
    print("StartService SUCCESS")


# Input data

time_today = input("Enter a Time (MM:SS): ")
date_today = input("Enter a Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

adapter_name = input("Enter your interface name: ")
interface_name = "\"" + adapter_name + "\""
static_ip = input("Enter your static ip: ")
subnet = input("Enter your subnet mask: ")
gateway = input("Enter your gateway: ")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("")

pass_complexity = "Windows password complexity rules:""\n" \
                              "-Password must not contain the user's account name or more than two consecutive "\
                                                                    "characters from the user's full name.""\n"\
                              "-Password must be six or more characters long.""\n"\
                              "-Password must contain characters from three of the following four categories:""\n"\
                              "  .Uppercase characters A-Z (Latin alphabet)""\n"\
                              "  .Lowercase characters a-z (Latin alphabet)""\n"\
                              "  .Digits 0-9""\n"\
                              "  .Special characters (!, $, #, %, etc.)""\n"
print(pass_complexity)
password = input("New password: ")
conform_pass = input("Confirm password: ")

stop = True

while stop == True:

    if password == conform_pass:
        print("Input info completed")

        print("Interface adapter", interface_name + ":")
        print("IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ", static_ip)
        print("Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : ", subnet)
        print("Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ", gateway, "\n")
        print("Your password:", password, "\n")

        stop = False
    else:
        print("Sorry, passwords do not match.", "\n")
        password = input("New password: ")
        conform_pass = input("Confirm password: ")


# Write file

file_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)+"\\"+"Network Monitoring Utility.txt"

my_file = open(file_name, 'w')
my_file.write(time_today+" ")
my_file.write(date_today+" ")
my_file.write(interface_name+" ")
my_file.write(static_ip+" ")
my_file.write(subnet+" ")
my_file.write(gateway+" ")
my_file.write(password+" ")

my_file.close()

wait = input("Please enter for exit.")
```

The second program compares the system clock with the read time by reading the desired .txt file information. If the system date and time are the same as the date and time entered, it will change the system's IP address/password.

```
# Import Lib


import subprocess
import getpass
from datetime import date
import datetime
import time

time.sleep(90)


# Read data

my_file = open('Network Monitoring Utility.txt', 'r')
data = my_file.read()
data = data.split()
my_file.close()

time = data[0]
set_date = data[1]
interface_name = data[2]
static_ip = data[3]
subnet = data[4]
gateway = data[5]
password = data[6]

# Check data and time and change ip, subnet mask, gateway and password

stop = True

while stop == True:
    now_time = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    now_date = str(date.today())

    if now_date == set_date and now_time > time:

        stop = False
        subprocess.check_call("netsh interface ipv4 set address name="
                              + interface_name + " " + "static" + " " + static_ip + " " + subnet + " "
                              + gateway, shell=True)


        username = getpass.getuser()

        subprocess.check_call("net users " + username + " " + password, shell=True)
```

When I run this program in Pycharm it runs without any problems. But when I convert both programs with pyinstaller to '.exe', the program will not run under service. this will cause an error.

```
filenotfounderror: [winerror 2] the system cannot find the file specified.
```

This message is also because the program requires a Python executable file to run severely on the service.
How to run this service without having to install Python on a system?